# Deploying/Using Code Contracts Reference Assemblies

Tags: .net, code-contracts

Once you generate CodeContract assemblies for an assembly containing interfaces, how do consumers of the interface use/make us of, the reference assemblies. Do you reference the "reference" assemblies directly, are do you simply co-locate the reference assemblies in some know location relative to the assembly containing the interfaces in question?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you just colocate the contract assemblies with the "real" assemblies, and the Code Contracts tool chain picks them up automatically.

Comment: So say I reference a assembly containing interfaces that I have generated code contracts for in a reference assembly. The reference to the interface assembly is "copy local". Where does the code contracts assembly go?

Comment: @Xhalent: I would *expect* it to be picked up from the original location, to be honest. I could be disappointed though :(

Comment: You're right, but I didn't find it that clear from the documentation. I have blogged about getting this work:http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/using-codecontracts-reference-assemblies-in-client-applications/